# When is it better to use ATFolder vs BaseFolder?

Tags: plone, archetypes

If I'd like to make a content type folderish in Plone, when is it better to use ATFolder vs BaseFolder?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Archetypes BaseFolder when you don't want/need all of the ATContenTypes additional features and metadata, so you will get a lightweight object, but commonly using ATFolder is a better/mainstream choice.

Apart of that: starting from Plone 4.3 is better to switch to [plone.app.dexterity](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/) framework and use *that* type of folders.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the main difference between the two classes is that ATFolder subclasses from BaseBTreeFolder, whereas BaseFolder does not. This means that ATFolder is much better suited to holding a very large number of child objects.
Also, ATFolder has

It's worth noting that most of the ATFolder logic now comes from plone.app.folder